# How to properly and easily assign data to variables from json?

Tags: javascript, json, riot-games-api

I am mostly a self-taught programmer and recently I've been messing around with the League of Legends API which uses JSON which I haven't used before.

This is part of my code which retrieves a player's ID:

```
function RiotAPI(phrase) {
...
this.request = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
    });
}
}

function getID(key, name) {
phrase = getPhrase(2, key, 0, name);
api = new RiotAPI(phrase);
api.request().done(function(data)
    {
        window.console&&console.log(data[name]['id']);
        document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = data[name]['id'];
    });
}
```

In this case the console properly logs the data in data[name]['id'].
However if I do something like

```
id = data[name]['id']
```

then the variable 'id' is undefined.
I understand that this is due to the nature of json, but what is a common way to deal with that?

Right now I have

```
document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = data[name]['id'];
```

which surprisingly does work, and it functions like a very sad variable. Clearly there has to be a better way to handle this, right?

Thanks

Comment: _"'id' is undefined"_, has nothing to do with _"the nature of json"_, it just means you are using the variable `id` in a place that it is not in scope (visible to whatever block of code you are trying to use it in). Show how you are using the variable `id`

Comment: *(Content of comment moved to Community Wiki answer)*

Comment: I *think* that this ultimate comes down to being a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function). But not enough to cast a close vote (since I have a Mjolnir on JavaScript questions and the site wouldn't wait for someone to agree with me).

Answer (score 1):

> In this case the console properly logs...`data[name]['id']`. However...`id = data[name]['id']`...then the variable 'id' is undefined.

No, if the `console.log` works, that code will successfully assign that same value to `id`.

> I understand that this is due to the nature of json

No, it has nothing to do with JSON. For one thing, by the time you're dealing with that `data` variable, you're not dealing with JSON. It's just a JavaScript object. JSON is a **textual** notation. If you're writing JavaScript code, and not dealing with strings, you're not dealing with JSON (it's been parsed).

Based purely on the name and arguments to your `getID` function, my guess is you're trying to *return* the `id` value from `getID`. You can't. Ajax is **asynchronous**. That means that when `getID` returns, the ajax call **hasn't finished yet**.

You'll need to pass your `getID` a callback to call when the data is available, or have it return a promise, etc. More in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function).

Here's an example of `getID` using a callback:

```
function getID(key, name, callback) {
    var phrase = getPhrase(2, key, 0, name);
    var api = new RiotAPI(phrase);
    var api.request().done(function(data)
    {
        var id = data[name]['id'];
        window.console&&console.log(id);
        document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = id;
        callback(id);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
getID("the key", "the name", function(id) {
    // Use `id` here
});
```

You've said in a comment you want to get the `id` into a global variable. If so, you'd do that like this:

```
var id;

getID("the key", "the name", function(receivedId) {
    id = receivedId;
});
```

...but note that `id` will be `undefined` after the time you call `getID` and before the ajax request completes.

Side note: Your code seems to be falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You'll want to be sure to declare your variables, such as `phrase` and `api` in `getID`.

Comment: Sorry, I probably meant to say the nature of Ajax (being asynchronous), not JSON. I am still relatively new to this so I get some terms mixed up sometimes.

Comment: @user5373954: Easily done. We've all been new to things. Sometimes more than once. :-)

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around this... I've tried a couple of methods but I still don't know how to do this. All I'm trying to do is have a global variable that stores the player's ID, but I can't get that data "out" of my ajax request. I did manage to use a callback to another function that does stuff with the data, but what if I don't want to use the data immediately, I just want to store it in a variable? How do I actually retrieve the data from the ajax request? Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @user5373954: I've added more above, but please do read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function), which I linked in the answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that the place where you're declaring the variable "id" is in the same scope as the place you're using it.

```
function RiotAPI(phrase) {
var id;
...
this.request = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
    });
}
}

function getID(key, name) {
phrase = getPhrase(2, key, 0, name);
api = new RiotAPI(phrase);
api.request().done(function(data)
    {
        window.console&&console.log(data[name]['id']);
        id = data[name]['id'];
        document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = data[name]['id'];
    });
}
console.log("id equals: " + id);
```

The above should work fine.